# Error to view my data from database

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new in this python and mysql. I attempt to view the first row of data from my database. This is my code:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                     passwd="", # your passwords
                     db="58c_t2d_10") # name of the database

# you must create a Cursor object. 
# It will let you execute all the queries you need
cur = db.cursor() 

# Use all the SQL you like
cur.execute("SELECT * 58c_10")

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print row[0]
```

And I got this error:

```
OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' 
                          to database '58c_t2d_10'")
```

I've tried to sign in as root:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
                          that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
                          right syntax to use near '58c_10' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cur.execute("SELECT * From 58c_10") 

u have missed from
```